# Numeric progressive matrix: 2-7-5, 2-3-4, 10-21-?

Tags: number-sequence, sequence, progressive-matrix

This is an interesting question that I got from an IQ interview test. This can have multiple answers but need a good explanation.

[image: First column is 2, 7, 5. Second column is 2, 3, 4. Third column is 10, 21, and a question mark.]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems like

> The numbers in the first column are represented in base 10 and the second column is the base the number is to be converted to. The third column is the result.
>  2 in base 2 is represented as '10'.
>  7 in base 3 is represented as '21'.
>  So, 5 in base 4 will be '11'.

Comment: While it's of course equivalent, you could also say rot13( qvivqr gur svefg ahzore ol gur frpbaq, gura jevgr gur dhbgvrag naq gur erznvaqre  va gur guveq pbyhza nf n fvatyr ahzore, jvgubhg n fcnpr va orgjrra. )

Answer (score 3):

It may be 8.

> Numbers from 1st and 2nd column cross multiplied to get the 3rd column.

> [image]